# добавить картинку как фон в swing

Tags: java, swing

Добрый день! необходимо заменить стандартный фон в swing на картинку, не могу разобраться как это сделать, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: фон какого элемента надо заменить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день!

На фрейме должна быть JPanel

На панель можно добавить таким образом:
1) Переопределив метод Jpanel

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("путь к картинке"));
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);       
}
```

2) Добавить лейбл

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("путь к картинке"));
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image ));
jpanel.add(label);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Paint extends JPanel{

    BufferedImage image;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)

    {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/aziz/eclipse-workspace/Оконное Приложение/src/ww.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); 
    }

}
```